Kibana canvas Error when Filter with Date
Can anyone tell the correct mapping format to be used for datetime field that I should insert in the Elastic search Index.
So that I can use the field datetime for filtering the data in the Kibana Canvas
Tried Data filter using datetime field in this format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss in Kibana Canvas it was working, But when changed to 2024-05-06T11:45:00Z format filtering is not working as expected.
